# Performance problems when calling a stored procedure

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL database with Azure level P1. I have a performance issue with it.

During one of my processing, I call a stored procedure:
- in entry, I need to have numerous data et I use a  NVARCHAR(MAX). My string contains 4000 characters.
- In the procedure, I do several processing:split of the string and then access to the database and insertion in database.

I have a lot of data, I call the procedure several times (because of the limit of 4000 characters). This procedure is call roughly 70 times per minute during 30 minutes.

I notice the DTU of the database is always close to 100%.

Any ideas of the problem and how to solve it ?

---

More details after first answers.

I have edited the DTU chart and add new resources ; CPU is also at 100%, and if I understand correctly it can be the processing of my input string.

I start to use a table valued parameter, but I am not sure how to use it correctly.

I created my table:

```
 CREATE TYPE Data AS TABLE
    (
    Idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Date VARCHAR(50) ,
    .....
    );
    GO
```

I added this table in input parameter of my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_process_data]
    @Id INT,
    @initial BIT,
    @Data Data READONLY
AS
```

What I would like to have, would be to fill this table in my C# code and have it in input of my stored procedure.
However, when I update my edmx model, the Data table in not there.

Currently, I call my procedure like this :

```
 var resultSet = context.sp_process_data(Id, initial).Single();
    return resultSet.ListId;
```

In the link proposed by Srini Acharya, I can see the use of SqlCommand.

Can I still keep my implementation and have an ObjectResult in output of my procedure ?
If it is possible, how to have my Data table in input parameter ?

Comment: Posting the Stored Procedure might help

Comment: Thx for your answers. I do not use cursors. The procedure is quite long (roughly 500 lines) ; in the procedure there are numerous database insertions in the same table (around 11 000 in 30 minutes).

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the DTU chart in the Azure portal to add other resource dimensions (CPU, IO, Log) to the chart to see which of these resources are being consumed at their limit. DTU is simply the maximum of CPU, IO and LogIO consumptions at any given interval. If you are hitting CPU limits, it could be that your string processing logic in your stored procedure needs to be improved. If you are hitting the IO/LogIO limits, you have more inserts going on than what a P1 level can support. In either of these cases, you have couple of options

1) To bump up your database to P2 level to get more CPU and IO resources. This is an easy online operation. However this has higher cost implications

2) To tune your application to reduce the resource consumption. This is highly specific to your application logic. If CPU is the bottleneck, you may want to look at using Table valued Parameters( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2013/09/23/maximizing-throughput-with-tvp.aspx) to shift the processing logic to client nodes.

Hope this helps
-- Srini Acharya

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added more details.